# Responsive Padding with Background-Image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a full width and height responsive home page with an image. The problem I'm encountering are padding issues. I cannot get padding to work when I display an image in css under 'background-image: url();'. The only thing that works is the margin property but it is not responsive to the height and only shows the top and the rest as I scroll down but I am trying to have the padding be responsive to the resizing of the height of the page. To show you guys more of what I am trying to achieve, I included 2 examples, the top with what I want and the second with the problem I'm facing. I've managed to get responsive padding to work while I place the img tag in my HTML but I cannot do so with the background-image property as I'm trying to put text on it.

```css
    .test img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 10px;
    }

    .wrapper {
    background-image: url(https://images4.alphacoders.com/432/43258.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="test">
<img src="https://images4.alphacoders.com/432/43258.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="main">
<div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u9t4hqqq/

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with using margin. It seems to look and behave like the image above it. https://jsfiddle.net/u9t4hqqq/1/

Comment: Or wrap it in another element and apply padding to the outer element (or just to `.main`, whatever works for your layout) https://jsfiddle.net/u9t4hqqq/2/

Comment: Are you looking for `background-position: 10px top; background-repeat: no-repeat;`?

Comment: @MichaelCoker if you look at this website here: http://www.madrougebeauty.com/ you will see that at the bottom, there is a fixed padding or whatever that seems to be over all the content. That is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @GabrielPozo ok, then I don't understand why you don't want to use a margin or wrap it in another element and apply padding to the element that wraps it. I gave you examples of both. Why doesn't that work?

Comment: @GabrielPozo https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/BRRowQ or https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/jmmbGG

Comment: @MichaelCoker They both work! and this solves my problem so thank you! I was not aware of the calc property and that was throwing me off. Thank you once again!

Comment: No sweat. I'll submit them as answers since you have some other answers now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `margin`, you just need to account for the vertical margin that will push your 100vh height out of 100vh, and you can do that with `calc()`

```css
body {margin:0;}
div {
  margin: 10px;
  background: url('http://cdn.thedailybeast.com/content/dailybeast/articles/2015/03/31/neil-degrasse-tyson-defends-scientology-and-the-bush-administration-s-science-record/jcr:content/image.img.2000.jpg/1432067001553.cached.jpg') center top no-repeat / cover;
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Or you can wrap the element in another element, apply padding to the outer element, and use `border-box` to keep the padding inside of 100vh.

```css
body {margin:0;}
section {
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
div {
  background: url('http://cdn.thedailybeast.com/content/dailybeast/articles/2015/03/31/neil-degrasse-tyson-defends-scientology-and-the-bush-administration-s-science-record/jcr:content/image.img.2000.jpg/1432067001553.cached.jpg') center top no-repeat / cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section><div></div></section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Padding does work, but you can't see it. If you put content within the div, you'd see the effects of any padding. What you want is to apply the padding to the parent, in this case `.main`. Padding by definition can not impact the background of the element it's applied to but rather where children sit in relation to the element's borders.

If that is somehow insufficient, you can simulate the look with `box-sizing: border-box` and use a 10px `border` that matches the body background.

Which raises the point that you may want to review the box model to learn better what margin and padding are and how they relate to elements:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model

Answer (score 1):

madrougebeauty.com uses a "frame" that is layed on top of all elements; it has nothing to do with padding.

To achieve something like it, look at the following:

```css
.wrapper {
    background-image: url(https://images4.alphacoders.com/432/43258.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Give your content padding so nothing gets hidden under the frame */
    padding: 2em;
    }
.frame {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.top, .bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  left: 0;
}
.left, .right {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
}
.top {
  top: 0;
}
.right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
}
.left {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- These 4 elements build a frame on top of the screen -->
<div class="frame top"></div>
<div class="frame right"></div>
<div class="frame bottom"></div>
<div class="frame left"></div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <p>Your content here.</p>
</div>
```